# Cloudflare Pages not displaying assets when deployed

Tags: cloudflare-pages

I am trying to deploy a website to Cloudflare Pages but I'm having an issue where none of the assets, including any CSS, are being shown on the live site. I am using Pug for templating.

Here's my project structure:

```
├── README.md
├── assets
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── faq.html
│   │   ├── pp.html
│   │   └── ts.html
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── folder
│   │   │   ├── 1.png
│   │   │   ├── 2.png
│   │   │   ├── 3.png
│   │   │   └── 4.png
│   │   ├── bg.png
│   │   ├── hero.png
│   │   ├── bg2.png
│   │   ├── bg3.png
│   │   └── bg4.png
│   └── logo.png
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── styles.css
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── src
│   ├── 1.pug
│   ├── 2.pug
│   ├── 3.pug
│   ├── 4.pug
│   ├── 5.pug
│   ├── 6.pug
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.pug
│   ├── 7.pug
│   ├── 8.pug
│   ├── 9.pug
│   └── 10.pug
└── tailwind.config.js
```

This is a snippet from my package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss build -i src/index.css -o dist/styles.css",
    "build:pug": "npx pug src/index.pug -o dist/ -P",
    "dev": "npm run build:css && npm run build:pug",
    "build": "npm run build:css && npm run build:pug"
  }
}
```

The commands and settings I have set render a bare HTML page, yet in my local machine it works.

I am not using absolute paths, my dist/index.html path to CSS for example looks like `<link href="../dist/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">` which should work and is comfortable as it works for the equivalent pug file.

Thank you for reading.